# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' out = [j.replace("on", "re") for j in out]

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace, attributeerror

I am trying to replace the words with the user word. Both the words are taken from the user. But i dont know whats going wrong in this.

```
def practiseeight():
    number = str(request.args.get('num'))
    on = str(request.args.get('one'))
    re = str(request.args.get('two'))
    value = number.split('<')
    print(value)
    out = []
    for i in value:
        i = i.split('>')
        out.append(i)
        print("This is",out)
        
     
    out = [j.replace("on", "re") for j in out]
    print("new list", out)
```

Comment: Try printing the values in `out` to see what they are. `i  = i.split('>')` created a list and that's what's in the list. Since we don't have your data and we don't  know what the replace is supposed to do, there isn't much more we can do.

Comment: <html > <head>         <title></title> </head> <body>      </body> </html>

Comment: This is my input for the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in  your code:

```
out = []
    for i in value:
        i = i.split('>') # so you are splitting i, split return a list
        out.append(i) # you are appending i which is a list
        print("This is",out)
    out = [j.replace("on", "re") for j in out] # now you are going through each element in out, each element is a list. List do not have replace, strings do!
```

To replace in a list of list:

```
out = [['abc'], ['abc', 'bcd']]
for i in out: # go through each element in out
    for j,v in enumerate(i): i[j] = v.replace('b','e') # go through each element in the list of list and replace
print(out)
```

```
[['aec'], ['aec', 'ecd']]
```

Comment: @kuldeepSingSindhu if you have time can you plz explain the detail understanding of second for loop(for j,v in enumerate(i): i[j] = v.replace('b','e'))     It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `enumerate` goes through the list and gives you index, value at that index. We are taking the value, doing replace over it and then updating the list at that index. Above j is the index and v is the value. You can print them to get a better idea!

Answer (score 0):

As rightfully mentioned by the other answers your variable 'out' becomes a list of list since you are appending 'i' (which is a list) into the variable 'out'. Try using 'out.extend' instead.

```
out = []
for i in value:
    i = i.split('>')
    out.extend(i)  ## this will add the element 'i' to the end of the existing list 'out'
    print("This is",out)
    
 
out = [j.replace("on", "re") for j in out]
print("new list", out)
```